# Cannot get automation extension from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium Webdriver (C#) I'm getting the next error from time to time:

> System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: cannot get automation extension from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -3.959 (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.120) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64)

The way in which this mistake appears:

> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1048 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 865 at AutomatedTests.DriverCover..ctor(IWebDriver driver)

So, it's happening in the next piece of code:

```
 public class DriverCover
 {
        public DriverCover(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            _driver = driver;

            _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); //There is my mistake
        }

        private readonly IWebDriver _driver;
 }
```

I use this class as a base class of PageObject classes where I use PageFactory to initialize elements of web pages.

I have chromedriver v.2.10
and Google Chrome v. 37.0.2062.120 m

In addition: at the same line I got another error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL `http://localhost:62407/session/021e05cd4c89abedb2abc77342b3bd7c/window/current/maximize` timed out after 60 seconds. ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed outat OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line 152 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\DriverServiceCommandExecutor.cs:line 73 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 852 at AutomatedTests.DriverCover..ctor(IWebDriver driver)

Comment: version of selenium is 2.42.0

Comment: I got this error as soon as I upgraded to windows 10

Comment: I had to `brew update && brew upgrade chromedriver` and I was good to go with Chrome v57.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba Any chance you can mark one as the answer if it solved your issue?

Comment: @JasonG this error occurs due to different reasons. I haven't encountered it for a long time. But I don't think any of the suggested methods is solving it once and for all.

Answer (score 19):

We were seeing something similar with Chrome and the issue came down to the way we were maximizing the browser before running the tests.

We switched from this:

```
Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

To this (for Chrome only):

```
if (typeof(TWebDriver) == typeof(ChromeDriver))
{
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("start-maximized");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath, options);
}
```

Comment: YAY!! fixes Teamcity build: Test(s) failed. TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException : Unable to resolve type: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:xxxxxx/session timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: @Aldracor it seems you have issues connecting to new Chrome v52 and new chromedriver v.23. They don't work with teamcity :(

Comment: @DenisKoreyba Well, actually mine now does (with new Chrome v52 and new chromedriver v.23) already had 4 consecutive successful builds on TeamCity, since I changed the maximized setting to be passed as a switch. Maybe there something else that changed, although that's all I changed...

Answer (score 4):

It happens because of Chrome Driver Mismatch.I had fixed this issue by upgrading my driver to the latest version.i.e 2.29(https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.29/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, worked for me
My chrome browser version is : 57 and Chrome Driver version is : 2.27
By adding the following code lines i resolved my problem.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("enable-automation");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Where did you add this code?. In which file, I have add this? conf.js?

Comment: @JeevaJsb search for "new ChromeDriver" in your project, we don't know what files you have on your system

Comment: This is doesn't help for me. I have done this with Firefox. That works better.

Answer (score 1):

THIS WORKS After googling through many many threads, I finally got the solution to such problems.

While most of the solutions above have pointed out the problem correctly which is arising due to bug in Chrome updates, follow below solution to get it fixed-

Download and use the latest ChromeDriver- compatible with the version of Chrome
Download the latest Selenium Driver from https://www.selenium.dev/ and execute the jar file on your system once.
Run the you code again to see the magic

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, same error, but when calling getScreenshotAs().... I had a old ChromeDriver and updating fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem during jenkins job run.
The fix which was working for me is to setup proxies in .bash_profile under jenkins user:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
nano ~/.bash_profile
...your proxy
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score -1):

Updating the ChromeDriver will do the trick for this problem.

Comment: Please consider adding more information to explain your answer. Code-only comments are not always explicit.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the feedback.This issue basically happens when we try to maximize a chrome browser in MAC OS