# ChromeDriver error "unknown error: cannot get automation extension"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

Since the 7th of February all my tests are failing with the same error; the log entry reads:

```
RESPONSE MaximizeWindow unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.21)
```

I'm not sure if this is caused by a Chrome update or something else - the message is vague enough as it is.

**EDIT**: I am using C#, and the latest Chromedriver.

Comment: What programming language? I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26283818/4280359) can be interesting.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, although it was working before the 7th of February so it's more of a workaround.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need the latest version of chromedriver.exe. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

This is needed for chromedriver version 57+

I was having this same issue. Once I updated the chromedriver version everything worked again.

Comment: Latest chromedriver (both 2.28 and 2.29) and Chrome ver 58 did not resolve this issue for me. Exact same error on `Window.Size`.

Answer (score 11):

Suddenly got this error -> *Additional information: unknown error: cannot get automation extension from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension..*

This issue exists even when using **ChromeDriver 2.29**
What solved it though was removing this line.

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
```

A quick fix but really not the one I've been looking for.
Would be great to still use the sizing mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

This could probably because the environment where you are running the tests is blocking all the third party extensions in chrome browser. Give it a try with disabling the extensions.

something like below:

```
ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();
o.addArguments("disable-extensions");
o.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(o);
```

Comment: Updating a driver didn't help, but this one did! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'n new to selenium/webdriver, where to put these lines ?

Comment: @Omar this is about driver instantiation.

Comment: In which file we have to add this.

Comment: @JeevaJsb In a file(test case) where you are invoking the driver

Comment: I have tried based on the following site. https://www.protractortest.org/#/. But I didn't find code to invoke the driver

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, it's related to the chromedriver.
In the [release notes of version 2.33](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt), it's mentioned that they fixed an issue related to resizing/positioning.

> Latest Release: ChromeDriver 2.33
>
> Supports Chrome v60-62
>
> Changes include:
>
> - Fixes a bug which caused Resizing/Positioning Window commands to fail on Chrome 62+.

Comment: this one exactly fixed my issue on 62 chrome

Answer (score 3):

Instead of downloading the chrome driver manually, it's better to update the version of `chromedriver` in `package.json` (or similar file) and fire `npm install` to get the latest version auto downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Webdrivermanager from

> io.github.bonigarcia library

It will automatically load the latest version of your's webdriver and so you will not need to update it from time to time.
Just call for example:

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
```

before calling the webdriver itself to get the latest version of ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 1):

Updating your chrome driver exe would not actually fixed this issue, if you observed, it is happening while you're re-sizing chrome
`driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();`

Try to comment this line and try again.

It's a quick fix, I'll update my answer once I find the root cause of this(however it seems because of browser update as nothing was changed in code for me).

**Update:**
For me, it seems to be because of browser update as once I updated again this issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue, too. I have replaced the existing chrome driver which I had in my C folder with new chrome driver downloaded from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads, which resolved the issue.

Comment: When was this version released?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just downloaded the latest release of chromedriver and that solved the problem.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Please don't use link only answers.

Answer (score 0):

With the last headless version, you can't resize the window as there isn't any window anymore.

For my own case, I was experiencing this issue with behat, I used to resize the window with previous versions of chrome of firefox, I surround the following line:

```
$this->getSession()->resizeWindow(1600, 1200, 'current');
```

with a simple check on the driver:

```
if (($this->getSession()->getDriver() instanceof Selenium2Driver)) {
    $this->getSession()->resizeWindow(1600, 1200, 'current');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had started getting the same error in April, shortly after this question. I was able to get around it by installing a new beta version and starting like so:
`webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone 3.0.0-beta4 --versions.chrome=2.28`

This was working perfectly until a few days ago. I tried removing the offending setSize() from my Protractor conf file and it works again. But whenever my tests start, it also spawns another Chrome window navigated to `chrome://settings/help`. Weird.

I checked my Chrome update history and see it updated from v61 to v62 last week, so that must have broken it.  I guess I need to update my driver once more.

Update: For those that want to quickly know how to update their driver:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.33
```

Don't forget to specify the driver when starting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
 for this -- it helped me after so much R&D

cannot-get-automation-extension

```
ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();
o.addArguments("disable-extensions");
o.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved post adding this comment, thankyou so much.

```
ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();
o.addArguments("disable-extensions");
o.addArguments("--start-maximized");
o.addArguments("--start-maximized");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

update your protractor and run your test cases it will start executing, there are few new stuff added from Protractor, this method worked for me.

update protractor - npm install -g protractor
update webdrvier - webdriver-manager update

Answer (score -1):

it supports the higher versions of chrome driver 2.29.

pls. find the latest chrome drivers in http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/