# RSelenium error "Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService"

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

Two days ago I was able to use

```
remDr<-remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port=4444, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
```

and proceed to open chrome, navigate to a page and login to it.

Today, following the same procedure, I got this error

```
Selenium message:Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'ATHENALAP', ip: '*******', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I am using Windows 10.

I have the standalone jar file to a folder with only Latin characters, and I open Windows PowerShell and run

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar
```

command. This was mandatory to log in to the page.

Maybe there is a problem with the version of chromedriver? (but still, why did it happen without changing anything?)

Thank you.

Comment: Give Splash & `splashr` a try! Docker container makes it super easy. But, also post the URL(s) you're trying to scrap as 70% chance there's a 0-dep workaround.

Comment: See https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/146

Comment: Goodmorning. I'm trying to scrap LinkedIn. Docker doesn't work. I follow the instructions of the tutorial and it shows an error. I will post it later, if it helps.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2614) also.

Comment: So, the error in Docker is:
Unable to stop: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The specified module 'Hyper-V' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Comment: I found a solution here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/65 and followed the instructions, but the problem wasn't solved. I was a bit confused at the point "In "System variables", create/update PSModulePath". I didn't see a PSModulePath, so i created a new one and just pasted the path  found with powershell.

Comment: Same here, and this one might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204586/chromedriver-error-unknown-error-cannot-get-automation-extension

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have upgraded:

1. Chrome
2. The Chrome Webdriver
3. The Selenium Stand Alone Driver

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my recent experience with Chrome web driver.
I am on Windows 10 and I am using protractor with node.js. 
I ran functional tests seamlessly until got the same error: `Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService`

After investigation of the issue I found that I have the most recent version of Chrome while chrome web driver is not updated.
So I ran

```
webdriver-manager update --chromedriver
```

The tests run fine again.

You probably have a similar command for your environment. I hope it will be helpful.