# Selenium Webdriver Error (Cannot get automation extension) while taking screenshot on Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am facing following issue when trying to capture Selenium Webdriver screenshot with Chrome (v60). I am running my tests using Selenium Grid and the screenshot mechanism works fine for Firefox.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.34 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890027/cannot-get-automation-extension-from-timeout-timed-out-receiving-message-from-r#26283818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the latest version of chromedriver.exe. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

This is needed for chromedriver version 57+

I was having this same issue. Once I updated the chromedriver version everything worked again.

Comment: Thanks Shubham, we have a massive nightly regression running across multiple environments, so was really scared to probe this option, I guess your answer reinforced the fact this is the correct option and planning upgrade properly really helped. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ChromeOptions` class to achieve this.

Try this below code:

```
ChromeOptions coptions = new ChromeOptions();
coptions.addArguments("enable-automation");
coptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(coptions);
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this option but it did not help however, upgrading to the latest version of chrome driver worked like a breeze. Thanks once again for taking time to respond to my question.