# Selenium WebDriver randomly becomes unresponsive with Chrome v64

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, circleci

When calling methods belonging to the Selenium.WebDriver class, the driver randomly becomes unresponsive. I have a fairly simple test that does the following:

```
driver.get(SOME_PAGE);
driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("auth", SESSION_ID);
driver.manage().logs();
```

I run the test 240 times using CircleCI, and it fails once or twice, at any of those 3 methods. The error is always the same:

> [1517000354.693][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer:
>   15.000 [1517000354.695][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.003

Note: I have a 15 second timeout set, so this sort of make sense. The problem is that the driver randomly becomes completely unresponsive. The entire test runner will be blocked at this point. (In CircleCI, the container will shut down after 10 minutes of inactivity.)

I am using Chrome v.64.0.3282, ChromeDriver 2.35, Selenium 3.8.1. This all started immediately after Chrome v.64.0.3282 was released.

Does anyone have any suggestions at how I might get around this issue?

Edit: I opened a bug ticket with Chromium here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2241

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Timed out receiving message from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450594/selenium-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer)

Comment: I think you claimed the answer on your own previous question [Selenium Timed out receiving message from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450594/selenium-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer)

Comment: This is a much more specific question than my question regarding the renderer timing out. This is specific to the WebDriver becoming unresponsive, not the renderer timing out (which is expected in this scenario.)