# "No such file or directory" error message upon completion of firefox selenium test

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, selenium, geckodriver

I have a stdout error message that occurs after running my python selenium test using geckodriver (firefox) but doesn't occur when using chrome.  **I can't figure out where the error line is coming from.**  It happens after the call to sys.exit() so somewhere during the cleanup process.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/ml/tbnznl592397p4h1svx4t5xr0000gr/T/tmpr8ypd0y1'
```

- MacOS 10.14.5 (Mojave)
- Driver info: firefox=67.0
- Session info: firefox=0.24.0
- Selenium 3.141.0
- Python 3.7.3

Here is the driver initialization for both firefox and chrome.

```py
    def createDriver(self, browser: str, headless: bool = False, performancelog=False, 
                     consolelog=False, verbose: bool = False):

        ## DRIVERS
        #chrome
        # https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

        #firefox
        # https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
        # 20.1 has a bug where headless doesn't work
        # 19 has a bug where it closes a frame?

        # safari

        # edge
        # https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
        logger.trace("createDriver()")
        if browser.upper() == 'FIREFOX':
            ## setting log_path to /dev/null will prevent geckodriver from creating it's own log file.
            ## if we enable root logging, we can capture the logging from geckodriver, ourselves.
            options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
            profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

            profile.set_preference('app.update.auto', False)
            profile.set_preference('app.update.enabled', False)

            # options.binary_location = binary ## use this only if we want to move the executable outside the available path
            if headless:
                options.headless = True

            caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
            caps['unhandledPromptBehavior'] = "ignore"
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, log_path='/dev/null', firefox_options=options, 
                                       desired_capabilities=caps
                                       )
            logger.debug(f"Driver info: firefox={driver.capabilities['browserVersion']}")
            logger.debug(f"Session info: firefox={driver.capabilities['moz:geckodriverVersion']}")

            if driver.capabilities['moz:geckodriverVersion'] == '0.20.1':
                if headless:
                    raise Exception("Headless mode doesn't work in Gecko Driver 0.20.1")

        elif browser.upper() == 'CHROME':
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
            options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
            options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
            options.add_argument("--disable-single-click-autofill")
            options.add_argument("--disable-autofill-keyboard-accessory-view[8]")
            options.add_argument("--disable-full-form-autofill-ios")
            options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable") # https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=402#c128

            ## ChromeDriver is just AWFUL because every version or two it breaks unless you pass cryptic arguments
            options.add_argument("start-maximized") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/26283818/1689770
            options.add_argument("enable-automation") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840128/1689770
            options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
            options.add_argument("--disable-infobars") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840128/1689770
            options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
            options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123152/1689770
            options.add_argument("--disable-gpu") # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959986/how-to-solve-selenium-chromedriver-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-exc
            # options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,960")
            options.add_argument("--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess") # https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chromedriver-users/ktp-s_0M5NM[21-40]

            if headless:
                options.headless = True
                # options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

            args = [
                "--verbose"
                ]

            caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
            caps['loggingPrefs'] = {
                'browser': 'OFF',
                'performance' : 'OFF',
                'driver' : 'OFF'
                }
            # https://www.skptricks.com/2018/08/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-selenium.html
            # caps['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'none'
            # caps['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'normal'

            if consolelog:
                caps['loggingPrefs']['browser'] = 'ALL'

            ## by default performance is disabled.
            if performancelog:
                caps['loggingPrefs']['performance'] = 'ALL'
                caps['perfLoggingPrefs'] = {
                    'enableNetwork' : True,
                    'enablePage' : False,
                    'enableTimeline' : False
                    }

            if verbose:
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service_log_path='chromedriver.log', service_args=args, 
                                          desired_capabilities=caps
                                          )
            else:
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, 
                                          # service_log_path='chromedriver.log',
                                          desired_capabilities=caps
                                          )
            logger.debug(f"Driver info: chrome={driver.capabilities['chrome']['chromedriverVersion']}")
            logger.debug(f"Session info: chromedriver={driver.capabilities['version']}")

        elif browser.upper() == 'EDGE':
            # driver = webdriver.Edge()
            raise NotImplemented("Edge not supported yet")

        elif browser.upper() == 'SAFARI':
            # driver = webdriver.Safari()
            raise NotImplemented("Safari not supported yet")

        # support is depricated for this -- should use chrome or firefox headless. 
        elif browser.upper() == 'PHANTOMJS':
            # driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
            raise NotImplemented("PhantomJS not supported yet")
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unknown browser: {browser}")

        # driver.set_page_load_timeout(self.timeout)
        # driver.set_script_timeout(self.timeout)
        return driver
```

In both cases I the driver sits in a wrapper that handles automatically quitting the driver.

```py
    ############################################################################
    def close(self):
        if self.driver is not None:
            self.driver.close()

    ############################################################################
    def quit(self):
        if self.driver is not None:
            self.driver.quit()

    ############################################################################
    def __del__(self):
        self.quit()
```

Calling close or quit before exiting the script doesn't trigger the error message which has me confused. I had thought the the error message was something in the geckodriver upon garbage collection, but if that were the case I would think I could manually trigger the error by closing the driver prior to sys.exit().

Anyone know where this error message comes from after a firefox selenium run?

---

**EDIT:**
It would appear the folder in question is the temporary directory `FirefoxProfile` creates.  I would appear that the `firefox.WebDriver.quit()` method is where the log line is coming from.

```py
    def quit(self):
        """Quits the driver and close every associated window."""
        try:
            RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
        except Exception:
            # We don't care about the message because something probably has gone wrong
            pass

        if self.w3c:
            self.service.stop()
        else:
            self.binary.kill()

        if self.profile is not None:
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(self.profile.path)
                if self.profile.tempfolder is not None:
                    shutil.rmtree(self.profile.tempfolder)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e)) #<-- this is the line where the error occurs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah!  I completely forgot I added a `__del__` method to the Firefox webdriver.  (this was before I had written the wrapper)

```py
# hack to force firefox to quit when closing scope
def __del_replacement__(self: webdriver.Firefox):
    print("__del__ called in Firefox")
    self.quit()
webdriver.Firefox.__del__ = __del_replacement__
```

The problem is there is also a `__del__` method in the wrapper around the webdriver which tries to call `driver.quit()` as well.  The problem was caused by both calls to the `quit()` method trying to remove the temp directory.  The 2nd was failing because it had already been removed.