# Getting org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Getting org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
Using Chrome 85.0.4183.121 for Windows just had chrome auto updated to 121 from 102 and have this issue coming up. The logs looks like it happens while taking a screenshot (using org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot). Is there something wrong with the chrome browser 121 release as their release notes (https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/) do mention they have tried to address a Out of bound storage problem with the 121 release but maybe there is a problem with its integration with selenium?

Comment: there is no issue with 121 build what chrome browser you are using ?can you share you class of taki screenshot by edit question

Comment: @JustinLambert I'm using chrome browser Version: 85.0.4183.121 and chromeDriver Version: 85.0.4183.87. Also I'm using org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot.

Comment: below code for taking screenshot , you should here add what are you try and what is error getting by sharing code snippet and all

Comment: I've occasionally seen something similar, but it appears to be tied to UI actions like "click". 

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.192)

I don't think this has anything to do with capturing screenshots in general, but it looks like something the chromedriver or chrome browser is trying to do.

Comment: This issue appears to be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959986/how-to-solve-selenium-chromedriver-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-exc

Answer (score 0):

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategy;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Screenshot123 {



    public static void takescreenshot(String filename) throws IOException {
        Screenshot screenshot=new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
         
        

       String dest=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\ScreenShots\\";
      
     
        ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File(dest));
    }
}
```