# ChromeDriver + Selenium Timed out Receiving Message from Renderer

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using ChromeDriver v91.0.4472.1900 and Selenium v3.141.0 and having problem with Timing out receiving message from renderer. I've checked all posts on stackoverflow and probably tried every link that I found on Google and none of them helped.
What I'm trying to do is to stop executing my tests when I get

> Timed out receiving message from renderer

because ChromeDriver won't execute any command after this warning happens

I've tried adding those 'cryptic' arguments to ChromeDriver like:

```
// ChromeDriver is just AWFUL because every version or two it breaks unless you pass cryptic arguments
                //AGRESSIVE: options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE); // https://www.skptricks.com/2018/08/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-selenium.html
                // this.chromeOptions.AddArguments("start-maximized"); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26283818/1689770
                this.chromeOptions.AddArguments("enable-automation"); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840128/1689770
                //this.chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless"); // only if you are ACTUALLY running headless
                this.chromeOptions.AddArguments("--no-sandbox"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
                this.chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-infobars"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840128/1689770
                this.chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
                this.chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123152/1689770
                //this.chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu"); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959986/how-to-solve-selenium-chromedriver-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-exc
```

As you can see, this is one of the StackOverflow solutions but it didn't help either.
I know one of the solutions is to find perfect match between ChromeDriver and Chrome versions but the problem is I have to be up to date all the time, so only solution for me would be to stop executing test and rerun it but I am not able to 'catch' that

> Timed out receiving message from renderer

and handle it properly.