# ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed! org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I'm using chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 and Chrome version =83.0.4103.97 for performance execution on Jmeter , but after few hours of test I'm getting "ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed! org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start" .

```
2020-06-05 14:42:53,966 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished:
111.10.10.79:1099-SCENARIO1 4-2 2020-06-05 14:43:54,175 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 120.000 (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97) Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: 'was-all-vm4-prf', ip: '111.10.10.79', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion:
83.0.4103.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Perf_VM_Admin\AppD...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52064}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(system), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 120000, script: 12000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true} Session ID: 1ccf7264d918b1eeb3a4d1b5246dddd8
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//span[text()='Climate']} 2020-06-05 14:43:54,182 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 120.000 (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97) Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: 'was-all-vm4-prf', ip: '111.10.10.79', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion:
83.0.4103.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Perf_VM_Admin\AppD...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51857}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(system), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 120000, script: 12000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true} Session ID: f0e86a7b96a3651a06e943b6b02200c7
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//span[text()='Log Out']} 2020-06-05 14:43:54,256 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 120.000 (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97) Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: 'was-all-vm4-prf', ip: '111.10.10.79', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion:
83.0.4103.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Perf_VM_Admin\AppD...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51892}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(system), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 120000, script: 12000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true} Session ID: 7ab6156cf4f914da0ed2358a14690625
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h6[text()='Climate2']} 2020-06-05 14:43:54,256 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 120.000 (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97) Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: 'was-all-vm4-prf', ip: '111.10.10.79', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion:
83.0.4103.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Perf_VM_Admin\AppD...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52246}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(system), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 120000, script: 12000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true} Session ID: d71d226f65b0eb42d66516ab8fa25d65
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//span[text()='Change']} 2020-06-05 14:43:54,262 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 120.000 (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97) Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: 'was-all-vm4-prf', ip: '111.10.10.79', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion:
83.0.4103.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Perf_VM_Admin\AppD...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52131}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(system), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 120000, script: 12000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true} Session ID: 84566adf1441f824b1800f01e58304a0
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//p[text()='Click']/../../..//button} 2020-06-05 14:44:14,847 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed! org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: 'was-all-vm4-prf', ip: '111.10.10.79', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251' Driver info: driver.version: unknown at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:179) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.getThreadService(ChromeDriverConfig.java:93) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:73) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:21) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.iterationStart(WebDriverConfig.java:205) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?] at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1] at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1] at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1] at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:135) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:92) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:2663/status] to be available after 20001 ms at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:188) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] ... 13 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156) ~[guava-25.0-jre.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:188) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?] ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're suffering from a [Chromedriver issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3511&q=renderer&can=2) so the only fix I can suggest is switching to another browser i.e. [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)

If you have to use this Chrome - you can try the following workarounds:

1. Before starting a new browser instance make sure that no `chromedriver.exe` processes are running, you can terminate them using i.e. [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) and [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) command
2. You can switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of using WebDriver Sampler, this way you will have full control on the [ChromeDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html) instance, for example adding `--disable-gpu` argument seem to help some people in [Selenium Timed out receiving message from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450594/selenium-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer) thread

In general the error means that ChromeDriver cannot communicate with the browser

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, your suggestion always valuable . I will implement the same and let you know .