# How does selenide find the element inside the document and IFrame

Tags: automated-tests, selenide

Looking for way to pick elements with **Selenide** inside the document which is render using ReactJs.

I need to access xpath `//h1/span[text()=' 1']` which is inside the document and Iframe. Is there a way to get that element and switch back to the main window?

Page contents look like below (Same page content in both images due to it being too long):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to succeed this using below method, Again but I got TimeoutException on time to time.

`[1627896042.179][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 30.000`

```
 public WebDriver getFrame(){
    try {
        return Wait().until(frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(iFramePth));
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("error in get Frame");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

For that, I used the below method before calling to the above one. (Check Iframe is available)

```
iFramePthElement.should(Condition.appear, Duration.ofSeconds(TIME_OUT));
```

But even now it getting failed sometimes same error.
`[1627896042.179][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 30.000`

Answer (score 0):

To switch back to the main window, you can just do something like this:

```
      switchTo().parentFrame();
```

This will take you back out of the iFrame context and back onto the main site (or parent page).

As for the Timeout issue, I think this has been covered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60167733/9350566