# ChromeDriver Session Timeouts in version 93

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome 93 was released recently.  Roughly around this time (Aug 31 at 4PM Central) our end-to-end tests started failing. These tests leverage Protractor, they are running via TeamCity, on a Windows build agent that has Chrome 93 installed.

We have tried to force a 93.x and a 92.x version of chromedriver. Both produce this timeout below.  We can run these e2e tests locally without issue. Any suggestions?

```
[10:23:38] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
10:23:38   [10:23:38] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
10:33:40   [10:33:40] E/launcher - session not created
10:33:40   from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
10:33:40     (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
10:33:40     (Driver info: chromedriver=93.0.4577.15 (660fc11082ba57405eca2e8c49c3e1af756fbfae-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#203}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
10:33:40   [10:33:40] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created
10:33:40   from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
10:33:40     (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
10:33:40     (Driver info: chromedriver=93.0.4577.15 (660fc11082ba57405eca2e8c49c3e1af756fbfae-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#203}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
10:33:40       at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
10:33:40       at parseHttpResponse (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
10:33:40       at C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
10:33:40       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
10:33:40   From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
10:33:40       at Function.createSession (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
10:33:40       at Function.createSession (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
10:33:40       at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)
10:33:40       at Runner.createBrowser (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
10:33:40       at C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
10:33:40       at _fulfilled (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
10:33:40       at C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
10:33:40       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
10:33:40       at C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
10:33:40       at runSingle (C:\BuildAgent\work\f3ee5d88fcfb5472\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
10:33:40   [10:33:40] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an identical question/situation, but there is a bunch of helpful insight in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450594/selenium-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer).

We're using protractor, so for us the fix was adding the `--disable-gpu` argument below, which was also hinted at a bunch in the above SO post.

```
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
      '--disable-gpu'
    ]
  }
```

Not sure why this was needed as-of Chrome 93 for us, but it is also listed in the [Protractor browser setup](https://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-setup) (claiming this is needed as of Chrome 58).

> As of Chrome 58 you also need to set --disable-gpu, though this may
> change in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem try using the following options (not nice, but it works...):

```
    chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-dev-shm-usage");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-browser-side-navigation");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-gpu");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-extensions");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=1");
    chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--aggressive-cache-discard");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-cache");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-application-cache");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-offline-load-stale-cache");

    chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("lang=de");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("allow-running-insecure-content");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("inprivate");
```